# Generic Web Video VR Player - IOS/Android with Cardboard

Tags: android, ios, virtual-reality

I would like to share some videos, so that my coworkers can watch them on their mobile devices (IOS or Android). I like the google VR SDK but i just built it for android and was not able to find a decent WEB VR Player in that quality. Any hints?

Comment: for iOS you can use this https://github.com/hanton/HTY360Player  (I have not run the code).

Comment: Then again, this is only for ios. i want to have a generic cardboard compatible player

Comment: Did you find any ??